# Cookie authentication - Always redirect to login Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I tried to use the sample code from github [Cookie Authentication](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Security/samples/Cookies) and integrate it with Active directory Authentication but I cant seem to make it run properly. Instead I alway get redirected to my login page. Please see my code below. Am I messing something?

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var CookieScheme = "YourSchemeName";


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddSession();


builder.Services.AddAuthentication("YourSchemeName") // Sets the default scheme to cookies
            .AddCookie(CookieScheme, options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/denied";
                options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
            });

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, ConfigureMyCookie>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseSession();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

**ConfigureMyCookie.cs**

```
namespace AuthSamples.Cookies
{ 

    internal class ConfigureMyCookie : IConfigureNamedOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>
    {
   
        public ConfigureMyCookie()
        {
        }

        public void Configure(string name, CookieAuthenticationOptions options)
        {
        }

        public void Configure(CookieAuthenticationOptions options)
            => Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
    }
}
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
namespace AuthSamples.Cookies.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

    

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(string userName, string password, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

            if (ValidateLogin(userName, password))
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("user", userName),
                        new Claim("role", "Member")
                    };

                HttpContext.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookies", "user", "role")));

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Redirect("/");
                }
            }

            return View();
        }

        private bool ValidateLogin(string userName, string password)
        {
            // For this sample, all logins are successful.
            string domainName = "SampleAD.local";

            string userDn = $"{userName}@{domainName}";
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new LdapConnection { SecureSocketLayer = false })
                {
                    connection.Connect(domainName, LdapConnection.DEFAULT_PORT);
                    connection.Bind(userDn, password);
                    if (connection.Bound)
                        return true;
                }
            }
            catch (LdapException ex)
            {
                // Log exception
            }
            return false;
        }

        public IActionResult AccessDenied(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            //return View();
            return RedirectToAction("~/Home/login");
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by always getting redirected to the login page? Do you mean that happens even after you login?

Comment: Hi @JeremyCaney. Yeah. after I enter the credentials I get redirected to login page again. It did'nt reach the post action login method.